# Understanding JavaScript Object.size() with jQuery $.isEmptyObject()

Tags: javascript, jquery

A JavaScript object is used to store error messages. Works great if there are errors, but if no errors (object is blank) the code fails. So, I added the jQuery `$.isEmptyObject()` test -- and now it fails if there is content.

Why does this code fail when trying to read the size of the object?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ts0s3d/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>If visible, code not work</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var tmp;
var objErr = new Object();

objErr['test'] = 'bob';

if ($.isEmptyObject(objErr) ){
    $('div').hide();
}else{    
    tmp = Object.size(objErr); //<=== fails here
    $('div').hide(); //if not work, js is broken
}
if (tmp > 1){
    $('div').hide();
    alert(tmp);
}else{
    $('div').hide();
}
```

Comment: what is `Object.size`? Press F12 and read your console.

Comment: try `Object.keys(objErr).length` instead of `Object.size(objErr)` a faster way: `for(var tmp in objErr) break;`

Comment: And there you go... the dangers of re-using poorly documented code. I thought Object.size() was a native function, but it is from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array.  Thanks gents.

Comment: Please add comment as answer for credit